# How to refresh RecyclerView from button on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an application with a `RecyclerView` and a `DialogFragment`, in the Dialog I add data to the database and display it in the `RecyclerView`. I tried to refresh the `RecyclerView` when I clicked in to add.

**This is the Fragment**

```
public class addAction extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText addTitle, addDesc;
Button add, clear,close;
Context context;
private DatabaseHelpher db;
String Title,Des;
public addAction() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addaction, container, false);
    addTitle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.todotitle);
    addDesc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tododescription);
    add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    close = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    clear = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addTitle.setText("");
            addDesc.setText("");
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().setTitle("Add Action");
    db = new DatabaseHelpher(getContext());
}
private void insert() {
    Title = addTitle.getText().toString();
    Des= addDesc.getText().toString();
    db.insertIntoDB(Title, Des);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (addTitle.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        addTitle.setError(" Title is required!");
    } else if (addDesc.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        addDesc.setError(" Postion is required!");
    }
    insert();
}
```

}

**and this is the MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<ToDoModule> dbList;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DatabaseHelpher helpher;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
        dbList= new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
        dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.AppRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                addAction add = new addAction();
                add.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
            }
        });}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: try eventbus http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/

Comment: how to apply this in my code ?

Comment: try to use callbacks, it makes your task easy.

Comment: i will reply by post here

Comment: ok thank you ,

how to use calback? i am beginner in android !

Comment: Does your dialog fragment close once insert method is executed?

Comment: thank you i find the solution

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Simply you can make interface and register it on button click and implement in your activity

Comment: @Piyush can you make this code and answer ?
i edit the method in the myhelper and its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Solution

cast activity and call your method like this:

in your activity add this method

```
public void myMethod(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//your code here
        }
    });
}
```

in your DialogFragment call the activity method after you cast it.

```
 ((YourActivity)getActivity()).myMethod();
```

Second Solution

add eventbus to your gradle

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

make a class that you want to pass to activity

```
public class MessageEvent {
    public final String message;
    public MessageEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

listen to events in your activity

```
// This method will be called when a MessageEvent is posted (in the UI thread for Toast)
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

register EventBus in your Activity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

finally send in Event from Dialog to your Activity

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
```

don't forgot adding this to proguard file

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
```

Comment: i try it but nothing is change ! i need when click to add button ,, refresh the recycler view !

Comment: if it work could you mark it as the answer @Mr.Android

Comment: this not work ((YourActivity)getActivity()).onYourMethod();

Answer (score 2):

Call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your Activity's `onResume()` method.

Comment: please post the crash log

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.example.todo.todoapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)

33 is your code !

Comment: what is at line 33?

Comment: okk can you post the full error logcat to understand it more clearly

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.todo.todoapplication/com.example.todo.todoapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.example.todo.todoapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)

Comment: it is showing error in onCreate() method but i told you to do notifyDataSetChanged() at onResume() method

Comment: ok i have no error but its apply just when close the app and open it again , my problem is ,, when i click on "add" button apply the data to the recycler without close the app

Comment: okk i think i got it . Add **dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();** before calling notify in your onResume method.I hope it will work

Comment: same thing nothing change

Comment: can you update your code in question for activity class

Comment: make a log in onResume method for the size of your **dbList.size();** and let me know after adding data from fragment